# SwiftUI hanging with @Environment and NavigationStack when passing Bindings

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment, swiftui-navigationstack

I've got a `NavigationStack` and I'm passing bindings to multiple children through a couple of different views. If I don't pass the children as bindings then everything works as intended. Also if I uncomment the `@Environment` aspect, everything works as intended. Not sure if this is a bug or an artefact of `SwiftUI` that I've missed?

Here is a simplified version of what I have:

```
struct Parent: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Parent, rhs: Parent) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var children: [Child] = [.init()]
}

struct Child: Identifiable, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Child, rhs: Child) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    let id = UUID()
    var name = "Child"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        MainView()
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @State var parents: [Parent] = [.init(name: "Parent 1"), .init(name: "Parent 2")]
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ForEach($parents) { parent in
                NavigationLink {
                    DetailParent(parent: parent)
                } label: {
                    Text(parent.wrappedValue.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailParent: View {
    @Binding var parent: Parent
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss // MARK: Commenting this out makes this work
    var body: some View {
        ForEach($parent.children) { child in
            NavigationLink {
                DetailChild(child: child)
            } label: {
                Text(child.wrappedValue.name)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailChild: View {
    @Binding var child: Child
    var body: some View {
        Text(child.name)
    }
}
```

I need to pass `@Binding` to both `DetailParent` and `DetailChild` as I need to mutate both the `Parent` object, and `Child` object. The `dismiss` comes into play when I delete the `Parent` from `DetailParent` view. i.e. I would like to delete a `Parent` object from the `parents` variable (using a callback function, which works as intended), and then `dismiss` (pop back up to the `MainView`) the `DetailParent` view as the content has been deleted.

I've tried changing how the `NavigationStack` works (i.e. using `NavigationDestination`) to no avail.

Comment: From the simplified version I can't see any reason to pass the information as `@Binding`. Are you planing to manipulate child in some view?

Comment: @Carsten yes I do plan on manipulating both the Child and Parent objectives in DetailChild and DetailParent respectively